# Open new gridview through Hyperlink

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

How can I open a new gridview through hyperlink on same page, I don't want to close existing gridview but want to show another gridview adjacent to this one, when user clicks on any hyperlink on this table. I have some data like below and I want to open a new gridview on same page when I click on any of these hyperlinks. New gridview will be having data from different table.

I cannot insert image as I do not have enough reputation but can share my HTML Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="UN_AT_Group">
    <Columns>
           <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="Group_Description" DataNavigateUrlFields="UN_AT_Group" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Details.aspx?Id={0}"
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Just keep the second gridview hidden on page_load, and make it visible with correctly populated data on hyperlink click of first grid..

Comment: Why dont you use a LinkButton and then handle everything in CodeBehind ? If you have everything on the same page ...

Comment: @DatRid- I am (newbie to programming) not sure if I can use LinkButton because I am fetching the data from database and rightaway converting them into hyperlink, and I do not know if I can do similar thing with LinkButton.

Comment: @user3581461 Can you show me how you convert the data into a hyperlink ?

Comment: @DatRid - You can see the line between Columns, where I am passing the Column header as DataTextField and UN_AT_Group as DataNavigateUrlFields, and this is asp:HyperLinkField so it converts that into hyperlink. I couldn't put the picture of my grid, is a problem. This is the link which I followed - http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Convert-GridView-Column-into-HyperLink-Fields-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: @user3581461 So you need the data from the old gridview to create the new one ?

Comment: @DatRid - Not entirely because this grid will show the list of the user groups such as Admin, ReadOnly and SuperAdmin and then if someone will click on any of these user group hyperlink, then new grid will be displayed the level of user group access, for example if I click on Admin then new grid will show that this user have Insert, Edit and Delete privileges and if it is a readonly then new grid will show that this user do not have any privileges. And I will show their privileges through checkbox, ticked for true and unticked for false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a LinkButton instead:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="UN_AT_Group" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" Visible="True">
    <Columns>    
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="GotoNextGrid" runat="server" CommandArgument="NextGrid" CommandName="NextGrid" Text="Show Rights">
                 </asp:LinkButton>  
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>  
</asp:GridView>
```

Do the same for you second `GridView` but set `Visibile="false"`.

and then catch it in CodeBehind: (Take care, make sure that what I have as Label here can also be something else... Whatever your `DataTextField` is.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "NextGrid")
    {
        LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)e.CommandSource;
        GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)lb.NamingContainer;
        Label lbl = gvr.FindControl("GroupDescription") as Label;
        string description = lbl.Text;
        GridView1.Visible = false;
        GridView2.Visible = true;
        FillDataForGridView2(description) //Fill the Data for GridView2 here and pass description as parameter
    }
}
```

Take care if you use `UpdatePanel`, then you need to add an `Trigger`:

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView1" EventName="RowCommand" />
</Triggers>
```

I hope this helps.

If you have any questions just ask.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and it is really a good way of achieving what I wanted but I have chosen another way. I am using a CommandField instead and adding it dynamically. However, your answer is correct for the question I asked.

Comment: Well thats nice also!