# (ASP.NET) How to do this: Button click in GridView to open pop-up window containing another Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

As from the title, I would like to do a pop-up window on click of a ItemTemplate button in a GridView(1).

The pop-up window will contain another GridView(2), and this one contains information(retrieved from database), this information is the same as GridView(1) and I only want the data from the row index of the Button.

These are some code that I have.
JavaScript:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("[id*=btnShowPopup]").click(function() {
      ShowPopup();
      return false;
    });
  });

  function ShowPopup() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
      title: "GridView",
      width: 450,
      buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
          $(this).dialog('close');
        }
      },
      modal: true
    });
  }
</script>
```

GridView(2) design:

```html
<div id="dialog" style="display: none">>
  <asp:GridView ID="gridviewpopup" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
      <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="companyLogo" HeaderText="Company Logo" ControlStyleWidth="170" ControlStyle-Height="120" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="companyName" HeaderText="Company Name" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="companyInfo1" HeaderText="Background Information" />
    </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

aspx.cs file codes:

```html
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)

        {
            this.BindGrid();
        }
    }

private void BindGrid()

    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM companyList WHERE companyIndID ='" + Convert.ToString(ddlIndustry.SelectedValue) + "' AND companySectID='" + Convert.ToString(ddlSector.SelectedValue) + "'" ))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        gridviewpopup.DataSource = dt;
                        gridviewpopup.DataBind();

                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

protected void OnPageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)

    {

        gridviewpopup.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        this.BindGrid();
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopup();", true);

    }
```

The above codes that I have don't work and I can't seem to find the problem with it, or I may have forgot something.
In case you are wondering which part, the new window does not pop-up.
Thank you.

Comment: You will need `updatepanel` to hold `GridView`. Then on button click, open popup and refresh GridView via updatepanel refresh

Answer (score 0):

1) You can put Hyperlink Button in Gridview and Provide  path for second Gridview.
You can follow this link also.
[Open new gridview through Hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24186304/open-new-gridview-through-hyperlink)
And Make a Connection Class for that.
2) Make a Gridview on one aspx page. And make another Gridview on another page.
Response.Redirect("~/secondGridviewpageYouwantTocall.aspx");
you can use this to redirect

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, I was not able to do exactly what I wanted, but instead of a pop up I used Button sender and GridViewRow to get row Index data and inserted using using DataBind to the other GridView and end the method with Visible = true, still wouldn't mind better answers to it.